# ggplot scales unit format thousands one decimal place

Tags: r, ggplot2, rstudio, tidyverse

Complete noob to R/RStudio/tidyverse.
Using R 3.4.0 "You Stupid Darkness" / RStudio 1.0.136.
Trying to format y axis to display thousands to 1 decimal place.
I'm using :
`scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::unit_format("k", 1e-3))` but displays as a whole number. How can I display 1 decimal place so instead of 30k, I get 30.1k?

Thx

Comment: can you add a MWE?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you need something more flexible, I suggest using your own custom function and plugging it into `scale_y_continuous` like this:

```
library(ggplot2)

# custom formatting function
scaleFUN <- function(x) sprintf("%.1fk", x/1000)

# setup diamonds dataset to display something in the thousands
diamonds2 <- diamonds
diamonds2$price <- diamonds2$price * 100

# make your plot and label using the custom scaleFUN function
ggplot(diamonds2, aes(x = carat, y = price)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  scale_y_continuous(name = 'Price ($K)', 
                     labels = scaleFUN)
```

Answer (score 3):

According to `?scales::unit_format`, you can set `accuracy = 0.1`:

```
scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::unit_format(
  unit = "k", 
  scale = 1e-3,
  accuracy = 0.1))
```